# How to convert Boolean type into "ON" "OFF" using String.Format

Tags: vb.net, formatting, conditional-statements, string-formatting

Is there are any way to convert Boolean type into "ON"/"OFF" using string formatter, like:

```
Dim inpValue as Boolean
Dim outValue = String.Format("0:ON;OFF", inpValue)
' should show OFF as output
```

without code or IFormatProvider?

Answer (score 8):

What is wrong with:

```
Dim inpValue as Boolean
Dim outValue = If(inpValue, "ON", "OFF")
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a crazy trick from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521079/net-tostring-format-documentation) but it's completely unreadable. I strongly advise you not to do this! If you are of nervous disposition, stop reading now.

```
String.Format("{0:ON;ON;OFF}", CDbl(inpValue))
```

This converts the `Boolean` to `-1` or `0` and then uses a [custom numeric format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521079/net-tostring-format-documentation/521129#521129).

Answer (score 2):

This should help you:

http://www.developmentnow.com/g/38_2004_4_0_0_238356/iformatprovider-for-boolean.htm

Answer (score 2):

There isn't any built-in support that I am aware of. However, depending on how much control you have, you can create your own format provider ([IFormatProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformatprovider.aspx)). Here is a link to a discussion on this: [bool format provider](http://forums.asp.net/p/1127044/1775562.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this using String.Format (without implementing [IFormatProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformatprovider.aspx) which seems like a overkill for your purposes), but you can do it in one line using [IIf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27ydhh0d):

```
IIf(inpValue, outValue=True, outValue=False)
```

Personally, I recommend using an If/Else statement instead of IIf, as IIf is not intuitive for some programmers coming from other languages.

Answer (score 0):

c# - not the most elegant but effective:

string outValue = inpValue.ToString().Replace("False", "OFF").Replace("True", "ON");

Comment: My eyes are bleeding!  String manipulation is a very poor implementation of logic.

Comment: No doubt (as I admitted).  Sorry about your eyes!

Comment: The C# equivalent of VB's IIf: var outValue = inpValue ? "ON" : "OFF";